# Is this a bug in the spoiler quote rendering?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, formatting, spoilers

I was writing [this question about what Mordenkainen's main school of magic would be](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/168833/35259) when I encountered a problem with how it was rendering spoiler quotes.

If I nest a blockquote (using the HTML `<blockquote>` tag) inside the spoiler quote, then any text after the nested blockquote is not hidden, even though it's still within the "spoiler area".

I'll show the bug here too:

> This is a spoiler quote and is hidden.
>
> > This is a nested quote and is also hidden.
>
> This should be hidden but is not.

I've also noticed the same issue on Meta Stack Exchange (see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260905)).

Am I just doing something wrong, or has something changed, or is this simply a bug?

Comment: It might be related to: [Some improvements to blockquotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343919)

Comment: Spoilers: spoiler markdown is really buggy and has been for years without polish. :'(

Comment: This has been reported on main Meta now: [Line after blockquote in spoiler not a spoiler?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347955) and a dev has responded that is by design (and tagged it as such). I have tagged this question the same way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After seeing the related Q&A on Main Meta (thanks to Rubiksmoose for finding it): [Line after blockquote in spoiler not a spoiler?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347955)

I have solved the problem I was having by adding a `<p>` tag after the nested quote.

---

Specifically, what I had before (what I used in this meta question) is this:

```
>!This is a spoiler quote and is hidden.<blockquote>This is a nested quote and is also hidden.</blockquote>This should be hidden but is not.
```

But it works if it's changed to this:

```
>!This is a spoiler quote and is hidden.<blockquote>This is a nested quote and is also hidden.</blockquote><p>This should be hidden but is not.
```

---

This is another example of the above but with more line breaks and `>!` to make it clearer:

```
>!This is a spoiler quote and is hidden.
>!<blockquote>This is a nested quote and is also hidden.</blockquote>
>!This should be hidden but is not.
```

Which should be replaced by this:

```
>!This is a spoiler quote and is hidden.
>!<blockquote>This is a nested quote and is also hidden.</blockquote>
>!<p>This should be hidden but is not.
```

---

Either way, if you include that extra `<p>`, it renders it correctly like this:

> This is a spoiler quote and is hidden.
>
> > This is a nested quote and is also hidden.
>
> This should be hidden but is not.