# Is it possible to have spoiler text in subscript?

Tags: support, spoilers, markdown

In [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/185580/how-much-should-arcane-lock-protect-manacles-from-damage) I had a parenthetical statement that was a little too long and would interrupt the flow of the question.  I decided to place it at the end, in a smaller font, using the subscript command as I see often see done here.  However, I also wanted to include within it a spoiler.

I found that I could make it a spoiler,

> like this

or I could make it subscript

<sub>like this</sub>

But that I could not have a spoiler within the subscript,

<sub>>! like this</sub>

I don't really understand what blocktext is, but there are plenty of posts on meta about blocktext not working in spoiler, such as:

[Is this a bug in the spoiler quote rendering?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9931/is-this-a-bug-in-the-spoiler-quote-rendering)

Is my problem an example of this?
Is there a solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Re order the tags:

> <sub>subscript spoiler</sub> | normal spoiler

```
>! <sub>subscript spoiler</sub> | normal spoiler
```

The line needs to start with `>!`. You can put subscript *inside* the spoiler, but you can't wrap the whole spoiler in subscript with `<sub>>! spoiler</sub>` like you were doing.